# how to send parameters of a form to rest service

Tags: java, html, rest, jax-rs

I m trying to send parameters of a form to a rest service. First user request the page with form elements with the method :

```
@GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    @Path("/create")
    public Response create() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("<h1>Create a new Event</h1>");
        sb.append("<ul>");
        sb.append("<form method=\"POST\" action=\"http://localhost:9000/events/created" +"?_method=PUT\">");
        sb.append("<br>title</br><input type=\"text\" required name=\"eventtitle\"/>");
        sb.append("<br>type</br><input type=\"text\" required name=\"eventtype\"/>");
        sb.append("<br>description</br><input type=\"text\"required name=\"eventdescription\"/>");
        sb.append("<br>location</br><input type=\"text\" required name=\"eventlocation\"/>");
        sb.append("<br>event date</br><input type=\"text\" required name=\"eventdate\"/>");
        sb.append("<br>creation date</br><input type=\"text\" required name=\"eventcreationdate\"/>");
        sb.append("<br>modification date</br><input type=\"text\"required name=\"eventmodificationdate\"/>");
        sb.append("<br></br><input type=\"submit\" value=\"create event\"/>");
        sb.append("</form>");
        sb.append("<li><p><a href=\"/events\">go back</a></p></li>");
        sb.append("</ul>");
        return Response.status(200).entity(sb.toString()).build();
```

After that i need to get the input values and send to the method :

```
@POST
    @Path("/created")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public void createEvent( @FormParam("eventtitle") String title,
            @FormParam("eventtype") String type,
            @FormParam("eventdescription") String description,
            @FormParam("eventlocation") String location,
            @FormParam("eventdate") String date,
            @FormParam("eventcreationdate") String creationdate,
            @FormParam("eventmodificationdate") String modificationdate,
            @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append( "<h6>Event sucessfully created </h6>");
        sb.append("<br></br><li><p><a href=\"/events\">go back</a></p></li>");
        Response.status(200).entity(sb.toString()).build();
        eventWorker.createEvent(title,type,description,location,date,
                creationdate,modificationdate);

    }
```

But it doesnt work at all. Any ideas what am i doing wrong ?

After submit the url is : http://localhost:9000/events/created?_method=PUT

Comment: What do you mean with "It doesn't work at all"? Is  createEvent never called? Maybe the path is wrong. /created vs /events/created ?

Comment: yeah create event is never called. Path seems to be fine . If create can be called, created can be also called or ?

Comment: yes, of course. It seems the path is not correctly to your createEvent method. Is it correct that the @Path annotation says /created while the form action is events/created? why do you need the _method=PUT parameter?